# Create a signature field within adobe with javascript and have it execute once signed without the properties dialog box

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, digital-signature, acrobat

I’m trying to create a signature field within adobe acrobat, which executes another code once it’s digitally signed without going to properties and selecting the “run once signed”. I have the initial part of my code which I use Action Wizard to execute javascript allowing me to create the signature field. However, the second part of my code continues to run with the initial code and does not wait until the field is signed. For better clarity my initial code will create the signature field and once signed will create a text field on the upper right hand corner of my page.

I have used MouseUp actions but my goal is to have the second part of my code run once signed and not just by clicking on the field.

Comment: *"my initial code will create the signature field and once signed will create a text field on the upper right hand corner of my page."* - you are aware that adding a text field to a signed PDF is a disallowed change?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't modify the document after signing. The field in the upper right will need to be added first. Add it as a hidden field, then after signing, turn it visible.

Comment: Could you provide a javascript example to do this? The javascript I used prior would populate the text box after a signature but it was due to adding the script to the “once signed” in the properties dialog. I’m trying to do this all without adding the script to the “once signed” section in properties.